# Linq - Group By Id, Order By and Then select top 5 of each grouping

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, take

Is there some way in linq group By Id, Order By descending and then select top 5 of each grouping? Right now I have some code shown below, but I used `.Take(5)` and it obviously selects the top 5 regardless of grouping.

```
Items = list.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
            .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Value))
            .Select(y => new Home.SubModels.Item {
                Name= y.FirstOrDefault().Name,
                Value = y.FirstOrDefault().Value,
                Id = y.FirstOrDefault().Id
            })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Use `Take` in the `Select` statement:

```
var items = list.GroupBy(x => x.Id)   
                //For each IGrouping - order nested items and take 5 of them           
                .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Value).Take(5))
```

*This will return an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`. If you want it flattened replace `Select` with `SelectMany`*

Comment: I used your initial answer with the selectmany and it works perfectly. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I was waiting for the time to go down :)